# how to get proper formatted text from html when tags don't have line breaks

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup, information-retrieval

I am trying to parse this sample html file with the help of Jsoup HTML parsing Library.

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <p> this is sample text</p>
 <h1>this is heading sample</h1>
 <select name="car" size="1">
 <option  value="Ford">Ford</option><option  value="Chevy">Chevy</option><option selected value="Subaru">Subaru</option>
 </select>
 <p>this is second sample text</p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

And I am getting the following when I extract only text.

```
this is sample text this is heading sample FordChevySubaru this is second sample text
```

There is no spaces or line breaks in option tag text.

Whereas If the html had been like this

```
<html>
 <body>
 <p> this is sample text</p>
 <h1>this is heading sample</h1>
 <select name="car" size="1">
 <option  value="Ford">Ford</option>
 <option  value="Chevy">Chevy</option>
 <option selected value="Subaru">Subaru</option>
 </select>
 <p>this is second sample text</p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

now in this case the text is like this

```
this is sample text this is heading sample Ford Chevy Subaru this is second sample text
```

with proper spaces in the text of option tag. How do I get the second output with the first html file. i.e. if there is no linebreak in the tags how is it possible that string does not get concatenated.

I am using the following code in Java.

```
 public static String extractText(File file) throws IOException {

    Document document = Jsoup.parse(file,null);
    Element body=document.body();
    String textOnly=body.text();
    return textOnly;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think only solution that achieves your requirements is traversing the DOM and print the textnodes:

```
public static String extractText(File file) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(file, null);
    Elements body = document.getAllElements();
    for (Element e : body) {
        for (TextNode t : e.textNodes()) {
            String s = t.text();
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(s))
                sb.append(t.text()).append(" ");
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Hope it helps.